# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (16384x164 and 256x256)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

```
## here is my landmarkembedding class:

class LandmarkEmbedding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, units, name):
    
        super(LandmarkEmbedding, self).__init__()
        self.units = units
        self.name = name

        # Embedding for missing landmark in frame, initialized with zeros
        self.empty_embedding = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(units), requires_grad=True)
    

        # Embedding
        self.dense = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(units, UNITS_ENCODER, bias=False),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Linear(UNITS_ENCODER, UNITS_ENCODER, bias=False)
        )
    
    

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size, num_landmarks, num_units = x.shape
    

        # Reshape x to (batch_size * num_landmarks, num_units)
        x = x.view(-1, num_units)

        # If there are missing landmarks, use the empty embedding for those positions
        missing_landmark_mask = (torch.sum(x, dim=1, keepdim=True) == 0).float()
        # print(x)
        # print(self.dense[0].weight)
        # print(self.dense.size())
    
        print("x shape:", x.shape)
        print("missing_landmark_embeddings shape:", missing_landmark_embeddings.shape)
        for i, layer in enumerate(self.dense.children()):
            if isinstance(layer, nn.Linear):
                print(f"Layer {i} weight shape:", layer.weight.shape)
    
        print(x.size())
        missing_landmark_embeddings = self.dense(x)

        # Reshape missing_landmark_embeddings to (batch_size, num_landmarks, units)
        missing_landmark_embeddings = missing_landmark_embeddings.view(batch_size,      num_landmarks, self.units)

    # If there are missing landmarks, use the empty embedding for those positions
    missing_landmarks = missing_landmark_mask * self.empty_embedding
    missing_landmarks += (1 - missing_landmark_mask) * missing_landmark_embeddings

    # Concatenate the embeddings along the last dimension (features) to get the final embedded_landmark tensor
    embedded_landmark = torch.cat([missing_landmarks, x.view(batch_size, num_landmarks, num_units)], dim=-1)

        return embedded_landmark

## here is my model:

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        # Frames Input
        self.frames_inp = nn.Identity()

        # Embedding
        self.embedding = Embedding()
    
        print(NUM_BLOCKS_ENCODER)

        # Encoder Transformer Blocks
        self.encoder = Encoder(NUM_BLOCKS_ENCODER)

        # Decoder
        self.decoder = Decoder(NUM_BLOCKS_DECODER)

        # Classifier
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(CLASSIFIER_DROPOUT_RATIO),
            nn.Linear(UNITS_DECODER, N_UNIQUE_CHARACTERS),
            nn.Softmax(dim=-1),
        )

    def forward(self, frames):
        # Frames
        x = self.frames_inp(frames)
    
        print(x)

        # Embedding
        x = self.embedding(x)

        # Encoder Transformer Blocks
        x = self.encoder(x)

        # Decoder
        x = self.decoder(x)

        # Classifier
        outputs = self.classifier(x)

        return outputs

# Create PyTorch Model

model = Model()

# Loss Function with Label Smoothing

loss_fn = scce_with_ls

# Adam Optimizer with weight decay

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), weight_decay=1e-5)

# TopK Metrics

metrics = [
    TopKAccuracy(1),
    TopKAccuracy(5),
]

# Loss Weights (if needed)

loss_weights = None

# Move the model to GPU if available

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model = model.cuda()

## here is the code I am trying to run

from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

# Define a custom dataset class

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        frames = self.X[idx]  # Access the 'frames' tensor directly
        phrase = self.y[idx]
        return frames, phrase

# Instantiate your custom dataset

train_dataset = CustomDataset(X_train, y_train)

# Instantiate the DataLoader with your custom dataset and batch size

train_dataloader = DataLoader(
    train_dataset,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=True,  # Set to True for training to shuffle the data
    num_workers=0  # Increase this if you want to use multiple CPU cores for data loading
)

# Move the model to the GPU

device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model.to(device)

# Iterate through the data in batches

for batch in train_dataloader:
    frames, phrase = batch
    frames = frames.to(device)  # Move the data to the GPU
    phrase = phrase.to(device)  # Move the data to the GPU

# Forward pass to get the predictions
    outputs = model(frames)

# Convert the predictions to numpy array and append to the list
    predictions.append(outputs.cpu().numpy())

# Concatenate all predictions into a single numpy array

y_pred = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)

print(f'# NaN Values In Predictions: {np.isnan(y_pred).sum()}')
```

here is my error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [38], in <cell line: 34>()
     37 phrase = phrase.to(device)  # Move the data to the GPU
     39 # Forward pass to get the predictions
---> 40 outputs = model(frames)
     42 # Convert the predictions to numpy array and append to the list
     43 predictions.append(outputs.cpu().numpy())

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Input In [34], in Model.forward(self, frames)
     33 print(x)
     35 # Embedding
---> 36 x = self.embedding(x)
     38 # Encoder Transformer Blocks
     39 x = self.encoder(x)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Input In [26], in Embedding.forward(self, x)
     18 def forward(self, x):
     19     # Normalize
     20     # x = torch.where(
   (...)
     25 
     26     # Dominant Hand
---> 27     x = self.dominant_hand_embedding(x)
     29     # Add Positional Encoding
     30     x = x + self.positional_embedding

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Input In [25], in LandmarkEmbedding.forward(self, x)
     30 # print(x)
     31 # print(self.dense[0].weight)
     32 # print(self.dense.size())
     34 print("x shape:", x.shape)
---> 35 print("missing_landmark_embeddings shape:", missing_landmark_embeddings.shape)
     36 for i, layer in enumerate(self.dense.children()):
     37     if isinstance(layer, nn.Linear):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'missing_landmark_embeddings' referenced before assignment

 I have tried print debugging but I still don't know what I am doing wrong. The size of frames is (1024, 128, 164)
```

.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).